# Are chained IEnumerable's methods Where and Select slower than doing them separately?

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I have some inherited code with the following calls:

First:

```
var pasajesDelServicio = venta.Pasajes.Where(p =>
                        p.ServicioPasaje.ClaveSolicitud == servicio.RequestKey &&
                        p.ServicioPasaje.IndiceServicio == servicio.ServiceIndex);
```

Then:

```
DatosPasajeros = pasajesDelServicio.ToList().Select(p => {
                            p.Pasajero.TipoDePasajero = (Dominio.Entidades.Cliente.TipoDePasajero) solicitudVennta.IdTipoPasajero;
                            return new DatosPasajeroCompra
                            {
                                Butaca = p.NumeroAsiento,
                                Pasajero = p.Pasajero,
                                IdVentaDetalle = p.IdVentaDetalle,
                                SubeEn = p.SubeEn,
                                MenuABordo = p.MenuABordo?.Id,
                                Precio = p.PrecioBruto
                            };
                        })
```

Would it be more efficient it the Where and Select calls were chained? Like so:

```
DatosPasajeros = venta.Pasajes.Where(p =>
                            p.ServicioPasaje.ClaveSolicitud == servicio.RequestKey &&
                            p.ServicioPasaje.IndiceServicio == servicio.ServiceIndex)
                            .ToList()
                            .Select(p => {
                            p.Pasajero.TipoDePasajero = (Dominio.Entidades.Cliente.TipoDePasajero) solicitudVennta.IdTipoPasajero;
                            return new DatosPasajeroCompra
                            {
                                Butaca = p.NumeroAsiento,
                                Pasajero = p.Pasajero,
                                IdVentaDetalle = p.IdVentaDetalle,
                                SubeEn = p.SubeEn,
                                MenuABordo = p.MenuABordo?.Id,
                                Precio = p.PrecioBruto
                            };
                        })
```

I've tried reading trough some docs, but couldn't find my answer. I'm really new to C#.

Comment: What were the results when you tried it?  More efficient as far as...processor usage, memory usage, what?  Unless I'm not understanding something, it seems to be less a matter of efficient and more one of necessity: if you need to project the full list into a different type, call `Select()`; if you need to project the filtered list into a different type, call `Where()` followed by `Select()`.  Or is there another option you're considering?  Also, that your call to `Select()` has the side-effect of modifying (a subproperty of) `p` is unconventional to say the least.

Comment: [do non english words increase the probability of receiving downvotes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266563/do-non-english-words-increase-the-probability-of-receiving-downvotes/)?

Comment: No, no, no to `....ToList().Select`. You are creating a list that is never used and has no reason. If you want to force Linq-To-Objects use `AsEnumerable` instead. If you want a list move it to the end. Apart from that it doesn't make a difference if you have two variables for the query or one.

Comment: @BACON I was refering to processo and memory, because I think (due to my lack of knowlege), that executing first the `Where` and storing the result in a variable and the executing the `Select` would result in a useless variable creation and a double iteration over a iterable (first over `venta.Pasajes` and the over `pasajesDelServicio`.

Comment: @BACON The modification o a sub-property of `p` comes from the fact that this method is doing a mapping between business a data layer objects. This could be done instantiating a new instance of Pasajero in the line `Pasajero = p.Pasajero` like `Pasajero = new Pasajero { // all the same properties except TipoDePasajero }`

Comment: Ah, now I see.  Be sure to read the Remarks section of the [`Where` method documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where) where it talks about deferred execution.  The query object returned by `Where()` will exist whether you explicitly capture it in a variable or not, so there's really no performance difference the two approaches.  LINQ methods are generally free of side-effects, so by modifying `p` you are modifying the elements in the _original_ list, `venta.Pasajes`, by calling `Select()`.  This behavior may be unexpected to other programmers.

Comment: @BACON Thanks, I will read those docs.

About the side-effect: Would you recommend to instantiate a new `Pasajero` then? I know this is a topic for another question, but is there any way to "clone" and object but replacing/setting a property in the cloning? I know it's weird but i'm thinking in something like Javascript's spread operator (I know is other language and paradigm, but I'm really new to C# so that's why i'm asking).

Comment: You could modify the elements of `venta.Pasajes` in a `foreach` loop before your LINQ calls, or if you make `ToList()` your very last LINQ call as others recommend you could then add `.ForEach(p => p.Pasajero.TipoDePasajero = (Dominio.Entidades.Cliente.TipoDePasajero) solicitudVennta.IdTipoPasajero)` after that.  Granted, that adds more code and means you're now performing two enumerations, but it maintains the expectation that `Select()` only creates new objects and doesn't modify existing ones/its input.

Comment: @BACON I would prefer not to do two enumerations. The path I choosed is instantiating `new DatosPasajeroCompra` and then modifyng the property in this newly created object. The Select still has a side effect, but now it's on the output and not the input. That makes sense for me. Although I will bear in mind  any sides effect for future uses of LINQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chaining itself wouldn't save you much processing since the exact same code will be executed in either case. However, since you have a `pasajesDelServicio` and a `DatosPasajeros` variables you would save some memory by only have one variable. Additionally, where you may be able to make this more efficient is by moving the `ToList()` call after your `Select` returning only a subset of the data instead of the entire entity (and doing the filtering after).

HTH

Answer (score 1):

Function chaining compiles the same as calling the functions individually. If you take a look at the interface for the `IEnuerableExtensions`, you'll see that its just an extension method that takes `this IEnumerable source`. C# Extension methods are just syntactic sugar and will compile as if the function's were called individually. As others have mentioned, its best to not call `.ToList<T>()` in your case as its a waste.